# Visual Studio Code and C programming

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf

I'm attempting to learn C and decided to use Visual Studio as a base for where I can practice my code. I have everything set up already and have started writing up code as well but I seem to be running into a problem where I cannot see the user input.

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char string[] = "";
    char reversed[] = "Placeholder";

    printf("Please enter an input string.\n");
    scanf("%s", &string);



    printf("Your original string is %s\n", string);
    printf("The string reversed is %s", reversed);

    return 0;
    
}
```

When I run this program, the first printf statement is never printed nor is the user input ever shown
anywhere (not in the terminal either). All it says is that the program is running. When I force stop it,
it will say 'Done!' and that's all that ever happens (I have to force stop because I never see the place to input the string therefore the program just keeps running waiting for an input). I just set up Visual Studio so it is possible I missed something and this is an easy fix but not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two completely different products.YOu tagged with "visual-studio" but your question is about vs-code?

Answer (score 1):

The string you're inputting is empty. First avoid naming variables "string" as in standard libraries there might already be defined one. And try to allocate more space for your string to be able to input data.

`

```
char str[128];
char reversed[] = "Placeholder";

printf("Please enter an input string.\n");
scanf("%s", &str);



printf("Your original string is %s\n", str);
printf("The string reversed is %s", reversed);

return 0;
```

`
Also, be sure to read more about arrays, strings and functions in c. The code you've written is probably not gonna work as you've intended.

Comment: No need of `&` in scanf. `scanf("%s", str);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems.

1. You're not allocating any memory for `string`, so when the user inputs something, its written into memory it doesn't own, resulting in undefined behavior.
2. Your `scanf` is wrong,, kind of. You must provide it a pointer to the memory where the input should go, you're providing the address of the pointer.  In this case, they're one in the same, but if that was a pointer to heap memory, for instance, `&string` would not point to the memory you've reserved.

Instead, try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char string[64] = ""; // string can now hold 63 user-input characters plus
                          // one for the NUL terminator, which scanf will add
                          // automatically.
    char reversed[] = "Placeholder";  // This reserves at least 12 bytes, 11 for the text plus the NUL terminator.

    printf("Please enter an input string.\n");
    scanf("%s", string);  // string decays to a pointer to where its memory is allocated.


    printf("Your original string is %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Note, you can still overflow your `string` buffer if you enter (in this case) more >= 64 characters, and you'll be back where you started.  I believe there is a way for `scanf` to limit the amount of input accepted, but will need to look up how.  Another option is to use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to accept limited input.

Comment: I made the necessary changes but the problem is still that there is literally no where for me to actually "test" this program out. I can run it, but it does not print anything out nor does it ask me for a user input. I cannot see anywhere for the user input (output or terminal).

Comment: @Interstellar then you have something wrong with your build/test environment. This code works as expected for me, I'm prompted to input the string and it prints out. I would post a godbolt string as proof, but I'm not sure that will accept user input. I'm dubious that what you think you're testing is actually the compiled binary of your code as you make changes.

Comment: Alright, I think I fixed the problem. Had to check a setting for the terminal. Thanks for the help, I didn't realize I had to write it like that.

Comment: *godbolt URL, I meant.